# General about case statement sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with names and ages. I am trying to understand the use of the case statement and I am getting errors when I try executing the following code. Its a simple program that would display the names of people over 30 years of age and the age if they are below.:

```
Select age,                                                 
case                                                 
    when age>30 then Name 
    when age<30 then age 
end
from tblPerson
```

Why am I getting the error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Sam' to data type int.

Comment: Is it because a column resulting out of an sql query can display only a particular type of data?? Like I can only display age or name in the resultant column?

Comment: Aside: Even though Microsoft can't comprehend the idea ([Sigh](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1546816/remove-case-statement-from-transact-sql-documentation).), `case` is an _expression_, not a _statement_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name and age are not the same datatype. You need to `CAST` age to whatever datatype you have for name.

```
   Select age,                                                 
    case                                                 
        when age>30 then Name 
        when age<30 then CAST(age AS VARCHAR(3))
    end
    from tblPerson
```

Comment: Oops..!! such a simple solution escaped my mind.. thank you sir @SQLChao

Comment: Just a follow-up question. Why do I need to cast the age as nvarchar to display it?? I mean the column in which either age or name will be displayed doesn't have a user-defined datatype. Then why does it choose to display only nvarchar values? Is it because of what I said earlier in my question: "a column resulting out of an sql query can display only a particular type of data?? Like I can only display age or name in the resultant column?"

Comment: @totalgadha all columns must have a datatype. In this scenario since `Name` was first in the case statement it tried to do nvarchar. If you switched the order it would have made it an int. I would also look into `implicit and explicit conversion` in SQL Server for further insight.